# problem with the biding between the ts file and the html file with the property [min]. Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im using Angular Cli 7.3.9

I have a date type input that should display, in its datepicker, from **the next day** according to the **current date**.

here's what I did on my .ts :

```
debugger
var minDateFinal ;
this.minDate = new Date();
this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate()+1)
minDateFinal = this.datePipe.transform(this.minDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') ;
console.log(minDateFinal);
debugger
```

here's what I did on my .Html:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="dateDebut" [min]="minDateFinal">
```

The problem when I consult the console I get the right result but the display does not work.
here are the screenshots to understand my problem :

when I override the property min with this code:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" formControlName="dateDebut" min="2020-10-02">
```

I get :
[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7IPq.png)

but when I use what I've done it doesn't work.

I get :
[What i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPqn3.png)

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when you do your date initialization in the ts file, your view (html) isn't yet ready, you will have to use ngAfterViewInit(), so in your ts file:

```
minDateFinal;
minDate;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.minDate = new Date();
  this.minDate.setDate(this.minDate.getDate()+1)
  this.minDateFinal = this.datePipe.transform(this.minDate,'yyyy-MM-dd') ;
}
```